# Invalid Cursor State When Running SQL Server SP

Tags: python

I am trying to run a stored procedure and im getting the error below. I tried doing AutoCommit = True but still no luck.

error:

```
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('24000', '[24000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid cursor state')
```

code

```
 def sqlConnection():
conn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};''Server=test;''Database=test;'
                        'Trusted_Connection=yes;autocommit=True')

cursor = conn.cursor()


return conn, cursor

def paymentsFPL(cursor, conn):
    cd = datetime.today()
    formatted_date = datetime.strftime(cd, "%m/%d/%Y")

    jobkey = 1
    date = formatted_date
    sql = f"exec pRptMonTrTypeSumm {jobkey}, '{date}'"

    fpl_payments_results = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()
```